# Retornar Tabla Temporal con Datos SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, tablas

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSecurityUser] (@Id_User int)
RETURNS 
@tableresponse TABLE (
   Id_Group int ,
   Id_Chains int ,
   Id_Merchant int,
   Is_Enabled bit,
   Is_Blocked bit
) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tableresponse (Id_Group, Id_Chains, Id_Merchant,Is_Enabled,Is_Blocked)
    SELECT Case when sswe.id_group is null then 0 else sswe.id_group end, 
    Case when sswe.id_chain is null then 0 else sswe.id_chain end, 
    Case when sswe.id_merchant is null then 0 else sswe.id_merchant end,
    ssus.web_enabled, 
    ssus.blocked
    FROM [security].[dbo].[security_users] ssus WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [security].[dbo].[security_web_profiles] sswe on sswe.id_web_profile = ssus.id_web_profile
    where id_user = @Id_User
    RETURN 
END
```

La Funcion anterior devuelve una tabla con Datos del Insert en la Tabla Tableresponse, por motivos de optimización deseo que mi tabla sea temporal, como pudiera lograrlo?...

Comment: ¿Qué te hace pensar que en una tabla temporal será más óptimo?

Comment: @Jachguate No me refiero solo al proceso de llenado de Tabla sino al funcionamiento general de consultas puesto que esa función la llamo mediante un Sp_ en lapsos de tiempo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no puede "devolver" una tabla temporal; puede crear esa tabla temporal antes de llamar a su función y hacer que su función escriba datos en esa tabla temporal.

Pero esto tiene una tendencia a volverse más desordenado ... necesita asegurarse de tener la tabla temporal creada antes de llamar a la función ...

¿Realmente ha medido honestamente el rendimiento de los dos enfoques? No creo que las tablas temporales sean siempre más rápidas ... el enfoque con la variable de tabla me parece mucho más limpio e intuitivo.

Pero puede definirlo en el procedimiento almacenado de llamada. Tenga en cuenta que esto solo funcionará para procedimientos almacenados. No puede acceder a tablas temporales desde dentro de las funciones.

Asegúrese de usar ##tableName para asegurarse de que la tabla sea accesible globalmente (fuera del SPID actual

Podrias hacer algo como lo siguiente.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[St_CreateTempTable]
@Id_User int
AS
BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tableresponse') > 0 
  BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE ##tableresponse
  END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE ##tableresponse(
    Id_Group int ,
   Id_Chains int ,
   Id_Merchant int,
   Is_Enabled bit,
   Is_Blocked bit
    )
    END
INSERT INTO ##tableresponse (Id_Group, Id_Chains, Id_Merchant,Is_Enabled,Is_Blocked)
    SELECT Case when sswe.id_group is null then 0 else sswe.id_group end, 
    Case when sswe.id_chain is null then 0 else sswe.id_chain end, 
    Case when sswe.id_merchant is null then 0 else sswe.id_merchant end,
    ssus.web_enabled, 
    ssus.blocked
    FROM [security].[dbo].[security_users] ssus WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [security].[dbo].[security_web_profiles] sswe on sswe.id_web_profile = ssus.id_web_profile
    where id_user = @Id_User
    --O SELECCIONARLO DESDE EL MISMO SP
    --DESCOMENTAR LA LINEA PARA VERIFICAR
    --SELECT * FROM ##tableresponse
END
GO
--USER SP PARA LLENAR LA TABLA
EXEC  [dbo].[St_CreateTempTable] 1
GO
--SELECCIONAR LOS DATOS DE LA TABLA o si se descomento la linea entonces comentar esta parte
SELECT * FROM ##tableresponse
```

Comment: La ventaja de una tabla temporal es si necesita hacer varias operaciones con esos datos...pero hasta ahí llega

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Quiero entender que cree mi tabla en mi _sp y posteriormente la llenes desde la función? como resultado sería posible obtener la tabla de salida en mi_sp?

Comment: Hola te edito la respuesta con un ejemplo